# Always-true tests failing in Angularjs -- Karma

Tags: javascript, angularjs, gruntjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I've not been able to figure this out for the life of me, but I am having serious trouble getting my tests to run correctly on my Angular app that I'm working on. I'm using karma to run Jasmine tests, and the problem I'm having is with my unit tests. I'm not sure what's broken, but I can't get certain unit tests to pass. They used to all pass just fine, but I've not been able to figure out where the issue is, but it seems like my controllers aren't being loaded into karma/jasmine.

Here's my karma.conf.js file:

```
// Karma configuration
// http://karma-runner.github.io/0.12/config/configuration-file.html
// Generated on 2014-09-26 using
// generator-karma 0.8.3

module.exports = function(config) {
'use strict';

config.set({
// enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
autoWatch: true,

// base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
basePath: '../',

// testing framework to use (jasmine/mocha/qunit/...)
frameworks: ['jasmine'],

// list of files / patterns to load in the browser
files: [
  'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
  'bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
  'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js',
  'bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js',
  'bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js',
  'bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
  'bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js',
  'bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js',
  'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  'app/scripts/*.js',
  'app/scripts/**/*.js',
  'test/mock/**/*.js',
  'test/spec/**/*.js'

],

// list of files / patterns to exclude
exclude: ['app/scripts/vendor.js'],

// web server port
port: 8080,

// Start these browsers, currently available:
// - Chrome
// - ChromeCanary
// - Firefox
// - Opera
// - Safari (only Mac)
// - PhantomJS
// - IE (only Windows)
browsers: [
  'Firefox'
],

// Which plugins to enable
plugins: [
  'karma-jasmine', 'karma-firefox-launcher', 'karma-coverage'
],

// Continuous Integration mode
// if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
singleRun: false,

colors: true,

// level of logging
// possible values: LOG_DISABLE || LOG_ERROR || LOG_WARN || LOG_INFO || LOG_DEBUG
logLevel: config.LOG_DEBUG,

// Uncomment the following lines if you are using grunt's server to run the tests
// proxies: {
//   '/': 'http://localhost:9000/'
// },
// URL root prevent conflicts with the site root
// urlRoot: '_karma_'
});
};
```

Package.json:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "^0.4.1",
    "grunt-autoprefixer": "^0.7.3",
    "grunt-concurrent": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-clean": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-compass": "^0.7.2",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-contrib-htmlmin": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-contrib-jshint": "^0.10.0",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "^0.6.1",
    "grunt-coveralls": "^1.0.0",
    "grunt-filerev": "^0.2.1",
    "grunt-google-cdn": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-karma": "^0.9.0",
    "grunt-karma-coveralls": "^2.5.2",
    "grunt-newer": "^0.7.0",
    "grunt-ngmin": "^0.0.3",
    "grunt-protractor-runner": "^1.1.4",
    "grunt-protractor-webdriver": "^0.1.8",
    "grunt-sauce-connect-launcher": "^0.3.0",
    "grunt-svgmin": "^0.4.0",
    "grunt-usemin": "^2.1.1",
    "grunt-wiredep": "^1.7.0",
    "jshint-stylish": "^0.2.0",
    "karma": "^0.12.16",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-coverage": "^0.2.6",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^0.1.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "^0.1.5",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-safari-launcher": "^0.1.1",
    "karma-sauce-launcher": "^0.2.10",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "^0.4.0",
    "phantomjs": "^1.9.9",
    "protractor": "^1.3.0",
    "time-grunt": "^0.3.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
```

Example test:

```
'use strict';

describe('Controller: NotifyCtrl', function () {

  // load the controller's module
  beforeEach(module('goodStewardApp'));

  var NotifyCtrl,
    scope;

  // Initialize the controller and a mock scope
  beforeEach(inject(function ($controller, $rootScope) {
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    NotifyCtrl = $controller('NotifyCtrl', {
      $scope: scope
    });
  }));

  it('should attach a list of awesomeThings to the scope', function () {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

Log output:

```
minErr/<@/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:5
    loadModules/<@/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3810:1
    forEach@/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:7
    loadModules@/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3775:5
    createInjector@/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3715:3
    workFn@/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2142:9

    TypeError: scope is undefined in /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/slider.js (line 20)
    @/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/slider.js:20:5
```

Karma output with LOG_DEBUG:

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin karma-phantomjs-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin karma-jasmine.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin karma-firefox-launcher.
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.23 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Firefox
DEBUG [temp-dir]: Creating temp dir at /var/folders/n4/d26v17pn1sg45jvn1c29274c0000gn/T/karma-69625537
DEBUG [launcher]: /Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox-bin http://localhost:8080/?id=69625537 -profile /var/folders/n4/d26v17pn1sg45jvn1c29274c0000gn/T/karma-69625537 -no-remote
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluded file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/vendor.js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Excluded file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/vendor.js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular/angular.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/app.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/amount.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/form.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/main.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/notify.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/slider.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/submit.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/tribute.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/services/donation.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/services/giftfold.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/mock/donationMock.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/amount.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/appSpec.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/form.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/main.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/notify.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/slider.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/submit.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/tribute.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/services/giftfold.js
    /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/services/panepasser.js
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular/angular.js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts"
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/mock"
DEBUG [watcher]: Watching "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec"
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/app.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/mock/donationMock.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/amount.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/appSpec.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/services/donation.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/services/giftfold.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/amount.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/form.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/main.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/notify.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/slider.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/submit.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/tribute.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/services/giftfold.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/services/panepasser.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/form.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/main.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/notify.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/slider.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/submit.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [watcher]: Add file "/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/tribute.js" ignored. Already in the list.
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/node_modules/karma/static/client.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/node_modules/karma/static/karma.js
DEBUG [web-server]: upgrade /socket.io/1/websocket/z06OOVspj9-9RTFD7gAP
DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket z06OOVspj9-9RTFD7gAP
INFO [Firefox 32.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.10)]: Connected on socket z06OOVspj9-9RTFD7gAP with id 69625537
DEBUG [launcher]: Firefox (id 69625537) captured in 1.723 secs
DEBUG [karma]: All browsers are ready, executing
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/node_modules/karma/static/context.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular/angular.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-touch/angular-touch.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/app.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/amount.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/form.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/main.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/notify.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/slider.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/submit.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/controllers/tribute.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/services/donation.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/app/scripts/services/giftfold.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/mock/donationMock.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/amount.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/appSpec.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/form.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/main.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/notify.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/slider.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/submit.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/tribute.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/services/giftfold.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving (cached): /Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/services/panepasser.js
Firefox 32.0.0 (Mac OS X 10.10) Controller: AmountCtrl Should create have a working controller FAILED
    minErr/<@/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:5
    loadModules/<@/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3810:1
    forEach@/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:7
    loadModules@/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3775:5
    createInjector@/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3715:3
    workFn@/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2142:9

    Expected undefined to be defined.
    @/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/amount.js:23:5
```

Slider.js:

```
   'use strict';

/**
 * @ngdoc function
 * @name goodStewardApp.controller:SliderCtrl
 * @description
 * # SliderCtrl
 * Controller of the goodStewardApp
 */
angular.module('goodStewardApp')
  .controller('SliderCtrl', function($scope, Donation) {

    $scope.donation = Donation;


    // set the default slide, and the upper and lower bounds so we know how many slides we have
    $scope.activeSlide = 0;
    var slidesUpperBound = 2;
    var slidesLowerBound = 0;

    $scope.moveSlide = function(direction) {
      if (direction === 'left') {
        if ($scope.activeSlide <= slidesUpperBound && $scope.activeSlide >
          slidesLowerBound) {
          $scope.activeSlide--;
        } else {
          $scope.activeSlide = 0;
        }
      } else if (direction === 'right') {
        if ($scope.activeSlide <= slidesUpperBound - 1) {
          $scope.activeSlide++;
        } else {
          // if we go too high, we return to zero
          $scope.activeSlide = 0;
        }

      }
    };

    // end slides logic


  });
```

sample content from the karma debug runner in the browser:

```
"minErr/<@http://localhost:8080/base/bower_components/angular/angular.js:78:5
loadModules/<@http://localhost:8080/base/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3810:1
forEach@http://localhost:8080/base/bower_components/angular/angular.js:323:7
loadModules@http://localhost:8080/base/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3775:5
createInjector@http://localhost:8080/base/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3715:3
workFn@http://localhost:8080/base/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2142:9
jasmine.Block.prototype.execute@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:1145:7
jasmine.Queue.prototype.next_@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2177:7
jasmine.Queue.prototype.start@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2130:3
jasmine.Spec.prototype.execute@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2458:3
jasmine.Queue.prototype.next_@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2177:7
jasmine.Queue.prototype.start@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2130:3
jasmine.Suite.prototype.execute@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2604:3
jasmine.Queue.prototype.next_@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2177:7
jasmine.Queue.prototype.next_/onComplete@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2173:13
jasmine.Suite.prototype.finish@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2561:5
jasmine.Suite.prototype.execute/<@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2605:5
jasmine.Queue.prototype.next_@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2187:9
jasmine.Queue.prototype.next_/onComplete@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2173:13
jasmine.Spec.prototype.finish@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2432:5
jasmine.Spec.prototype.execute/<@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2459:5
jasmine.Queue.prototype.next_@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2187:9
jasmine.Queue.prototype.next_/onComplete/<@http://localhost:8080/base/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js:2167:13
```

I can test the app's dependencies just fine, but other tests won't pass even on always-true situations. I've tried downgrading angular, clearing caches, making sure all of my files are included (still the same error), changing the debug level, but nothing has worked. Any help would be awesome!Thanks!

Comment: If the tests were running the something you edited must be broken. Have you tried unloading a few files at a time until you pin-point where the problem might be.

Comment: can you also include the contents of `/Users/mthomas/Code/apps/pro-forma/test/spec/controllers/slider.js`?

Comment: The error above save "scope is undefined" in the controller that Kristian mentioned above. You probably meant to type `$scope`?

Comment: Strange, it's ok http://jsfiddle.net/bBL9P/21/. Try to refresh karma.conf.js, check your paths, debug in browser.

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone; I've tried looking back at my commits and reverting to earlier ones, but can't find anything that would have caused it. I reverted my versions and karma.conf.js to versions where it was working; the error is the funkiest part. Not able to find anything about it online.

Comment: Another problem is that my travis build indicated passing when some of the tests were failing and I was running e2e tests locally, so I'm not sure about when I would have broken it. I've tried loading in every single dep file, but that doesn't fix it either.

Comment: @SunilD. `$scope` gets aliased to `scope`; the same test passes in a clean yeoman angular scaffold, so I know it's not that.

Comment: I can post more of my setup if that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Take out `app/scripts/*.js` from karma conf file.

Answer (score 0):

After removing `src/**/*.js` in `karma-unit.tpl.js`

As a temporary word around, change

```
browsers: [
    'Firefox'
]
```

to

```
browsers: [
  'firefox'
]
```

and run graunt watch.

As for browser name mismatches, if it asks for Plugins, press <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>.